# Using fscanf to store floats and strings into an array of structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, scanf

The program I'm working on should pull data from a pre-existing text file, edit the data, and rewrite it onto a new text file. I've gotten most of it to work but it doesn't store any of the scanned data into my array. When I call my print to file function (which I'm fairly certain works fine), nothing is printed to the new file.

The whole code file is rather long so I'm only including a bit of it. Let me know if you need any clarification; any advise or ideas would be a great help! Thank you in advance!

The file it should be pulling from has a default format of

```
Name:\n\t Hours Worked: \n\tWeekly Pay: \n\tTaxes Paid: \n\tTake-home Wage:
```

Code

```
    // in main (already declared and initialized all variables
    printf("Please enter the name of the text file you'd like to read from: ");
    scanf(" %s",fileName);
    fp= (fopen(&fileName, "r+"));
    if (fp ==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open %s", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        loadFromFile(&employeeInfo[i],fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    break;

int loadFromFile(struct Employee *employee,FILE *fp){
    static int employeeNumb;
    fscanf(fp, " %*[^:]: %s", employee->name);
    if ((*employee).name==feof(fp))
        printf("fscanf did not store properly");
    fscanf(fp," %*[^:]: %f", &employee->hoursWorked);
    fscanf(fp," %*[^$]$ %f", &employee->weeklyPay);
    fscanf(fp, " %*[^$]$ %f",  &employee->taxesPaid);
    fscanf(fp, " %*[^$]$ %*s");
    employeeNumb++;
    return employeeNumb;
}
```

**EDIT**: Added my print to file function

```
void saveToFile(struct Employee employee[], int employeeNumb){
FILE *fp;
char newFile[40];
printf("Please enter the name of the text file you'd like to create or overwrite: ");
scanf(" %s",newFile);
fp= fopen(newFile, "w+");//r+ if do NOT want to overwrite or a+ if append
if (fp ==NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open %s", newFile);
    exit(1);
}
for(int i=0; i<employeeNumb; i++){
    printToFile(fp,&employee[i]);
}
fclose(fp);}

 void printToFile(FILE *fp,struct Employee *employee){
fprintf(fp, "\nName: %s", (*employee).name);
fprintf(fp,"\n\tHours Worked: %g", (*employee).hoursWorked);
fprintf(fp,"\n\tWeekly Wage: $%.2f", (*employee).weeklyPay);
fprintf(fp, "\n\tTaxes Paid: $%.2f", (*employee).taxesPaid);
fprintf(fp, "\n\tTake-home Wage: $%.2f", ((*employee).weeklyPay)-(*employee).taxesPaid);

}
```

**EDIT 2**: Added struct definition

```
struct Employee {
char name[40];
float weeklyPay;
float hoursWorked;
float taxesPaid;};
```

Comment: `fopen(&fileName, "r+")` --> `fopen(fileName, "r+")`

Comment: Can you show the part of code where you are actually writing in your file (fwrite or fput stuff) ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks for pointing that out! It was giving me a warning but the file still opened successfully so I don't believe that's the main problem. I will fix it though!

Comment: Can you show *exactly* what a record of your input file looks like?  Your `fscanf()` format strings may not be right... And also `struct Employee`... the other arguments look off too (unless your struct contains pointers).

Comment: Just add it the way you added the code.  Just need to see the definition of your struct, and exactly what the text of the records in the file looks like.  Or is it the same format as your output?

Comment: @Dmitri It's the same format as the output. The idea is that you initially make a file using this program and then later pull the information out the file previously made.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, " %*[^:], %s", employee->name);` --> `fscanf(fp, " %*[^:]: %s", employee->name);`

Comment: `fscanf(fp," %*[^:], %f", employee->weeklyPay);`, for example, expects to read a comma (and won't read the colon or dollar sign)... and you're passing a `float` when you should pass a pointer to one.

Comment: Also, the `%s` for `fscanf()` will not read a string that includes whitespace (would only read the first word), so if you have eg. first and last name in your Name field you'll have problems.  Also, your read code expects exactly four lines/fields per record, so hopefully that last field in your output isn't in your input file.

Comment: @Dmitri Sorry bit confused on that, shouldn't it expect to read the colon only and ignore it? I will replace the colon with a dollar sign for the floats, thanks for catching that! I don't quite understand what you mean by passing a pointer instead of a float. Do you mean it should read     &employee->weeklyPay?

Comment: `%*[^:]` reads *up to* a colon, but leaves the colon in the stream.  You'd have to explicitly read the colon afterward.  And yes, `&employee->weeklyPay`.... you need to pass a pointer to let `fscanf()` access the `float` properly.

Comment: @Dmitri that last record is in my input file but I think I know how to fix that, I'll edit it in.

Comment: Consider `fscanf(fp, " %*[^:]: %s", employee->name);`.  What happens when input begins with `':'`? --> Nothing is saved in `employee->name`  `':'` is not consumed.  What happens when input is at end-of-file? the previous `feof()` does not help.  Nothing is saved in `employee->name`    So steps 1- check the results of a `fscanf()` against the expected return value (usually 1 in these cases.)

Comment: @chux I was under the impression that by typing : and then a space we are telling fscanf to ignore them. I did do some research on it and heard that fscanf is unable to do these types of things while scanf can, but I'm not sure how else to store the data. Sorry but I do not understand why feof() wouldn't help, as I am looping the function call. I will add an if statement to check what is stored as a result of fscanf()! Thanks for the input!

Comment: `feof()` doesn't exactly indicate end of file... it indicates whether a previous read failure was caused by end of file (kind of).  You need to check the return from `fscanf()` to see if it read the fields... if `fscanf()` returns EOF, then you can use `feof()` if you care to know whether it reached the end of the file or hit some other error.

Comment: `%*[^:]` only ignores `':'`  if it encounters non-`':'` before encountering a `':'`.  If the _first_ character is `':'`, the function returns immediately. The following `": %s"` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Dmitri Alright, so to check I added it in. It did not print the error message when I ran it so I'm assuming that is not the issue. It still does not store anything into the struct array though, any other ideas?

Comment: @chux Oh alright I did not realize that. The input will always appear as formatted in the output, will that still be a problem? If so, how else would I be able to format the fscanf to avoid that? Sorry, I am not that familiar with the formatting that well.

Comment: when using any of the `scanf()` family of functions, with the `%s` format specifier, ALWAYS include a max length modifier (that is 1 less than the actual length of the input field) so the input cannot overrun the input field.  Such and overrun results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when outputting an error message, the code should output to stderr.  and it is a really good idea to include the reason the OS thinks the error occurred.  so replace: `printf("Unable to open %s", fileName);` with `char errorMsg[50]; sprintf(errorMsg, "Unable to open %s", fileName); perror( errorMsg );`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to gather all together.
My testfile (the format you gave is a hard to understand (more likely: I'm too stupid to understand), just adapt accordingly)

```
Name: 6ZjQPZJniP
        Hours Worked: 35.0
        Weekly Wage: $12.0
        Taxes Paid: $65.0
Name: pOmMgjgPHD
        Hours Worked: 20.0
        Weekly Wage: $49.0
        Taxes Paid: $85.0
Name: TRTxUptiD2
        Hours Worked: 43.0
        Weekly Wage: $23.0
        Taxes Paid: $42.0
Name: q5mQ5Yy0QA
        Hours Worked: 22.0
        Weekly Wage: $97.0
        Taxes Paid: $67.0
Name: saiZAKNJSy
        Hours Worked: 59.0
        Weekly Wage: $99.0
        Taxes Paid: $70.0
Name: lh3ZnB81jI
        Hours Worked: 19.0
        Weekly Wage: $36.0
        Taxes Paid: $49.0
Name: H8mw8eckfB
        Hours Worked: 35.0
        Weekly Wage: $24.0
        Taxes Paid: $45.0
Name: t9E4sQnmlG
        Hours Worked: 64.0
        Weekly Wage: $14.0
        Taxes Paid: $63.0
Name: KggqJYULf5
        Hours Worked: 84.0
        Weekly Wage: $80.0
        Taxes Paid: $15.0
Name: Emov5IhBce
        Hours Worked: 24.0
        Weekly Wage: $35.0
        Taxes Paid: $74.0
```

(ends with newline!)

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    // ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

typedef struct Employee {
  char name[40];
  float hoursWorked;
  float weeklyPay;
  float taxesPaid;
} Employee;
// all structs
void saveToFile(Employee ** employee, int employeeNumb);
// one struct
void printToFile(FILE * fp, Employee * employee);
// one struct
int loadFromFile(Employee * employee, FILE * fp);

static int employeeNumb;

void saveToFile(Employee ** employee, int employeeNumb)
{
  FILE *fp;
  char newFile[128];
  printf
      ("Please enter the name of the text file you'd like to create or overwrite: ");
  scanf(" %s", newFile);
  fp = fopen(newFile, "w+");    //r+ if do NOT want to overwrite or a+ if append
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open %s", newFile);
    exit(1);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < employeeNumb; i++) {
    printToFile(fp, employee[i]);
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

void printToFile(FILE * fp, Employee * employee)
{
  fprintf(fp, "\nName: %s", employee->name);
  fprintf(fp, "\n\tHours Worked: %f", employee->hoursWorked);
  fprintf(fp, "\n\tWeekly Wage: $%.2f", employee->weeklyPay);
  fprintf(fp, "\n\tTaxes Paid: $%.2f", employee->taxesPaid);
  fprintf(fp, "\n\tTake-home Wage: $%.2f",
      (employee->weeklyPay) - employee->taxesPaid);
}

int loadFromFile(Employee * employee, FILE * fp)
{
  if (feof(fp)){
    return employeeNumb;
  }
  // I just c&p'd the format. Works because the format is fixed
  // Keep it simple when you can!
  fscanf(fp, "Name: %s\n", employee->name);
  fscanf(fp, "\tHours Worked: %f\n", &employee->hoursWorked);
  fscanf(fp, "\tWeekly Wage: $%f\n", &employee->weeklyPay);
  fscanf(fp, "\tTaxes Paid: $%f\n", &employee->taxesPaid);
  employeeNumb++;
  return employeeNumb;
}

int main()
{
  char fileName[128];
  FILE *fp;
  // pointer to the pointers to the (10) Employee structs
  Employee **employeeInfo;
  int i;

  printf("Please enter the name of the text file you'd like to read from: ");
  scanf(" %s", fileName);
  fp = (fopen(fileName, "r"));
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s", fileName);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // we need enough memory to safe ten structs
  // at first allocate memory for 10 pointers (to the structs)
  employeeInfo = malloc(10 * sizeof(Employee*));
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // for each pointer allocate memory for one struct
    employeeInfo[i] = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // loadFromFile() takes one struct
    loadFromFile(employeeInfo[i], fp);
  }

  // clean up
  fclose(fp);
  // saveToFile() takes all structs
  saveToFile(employeeInfo, employeeNumb);
  // free memory of the individual structs
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    free(employeeInfo[i]);
  }
  // free the memory holding the 10 pointers
  free(employeeInfo);
  // say Bye!
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Not perfect but you should have something to build upon.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'm sorry I couldn't of been clearer; I'm quite new to programming. I'm a bit confused as to why you would use a pointer to the array of structures. But thank you! It will definitely be a big help to me!

Comment: You wanted pointers, your use of `->` indicated that. I just cleaned it up a little bit and used pointers throughout. The only disadvantage is that you have to take care of the memory yourself. It's also how you do it if you need some larger amount of memory and/or do not know how much in advance. Stack memory is expensive, you don't waste it, heap memory on the other side is cheap and flexible.

Comment: The `" "` in `scanf(" %s", newFile);` serves little purpose.  `"%s"` by itself consumes and discards leading space.  Without a width limit `scanf(" %s", newFile);` is as safe as `gets(newFile);`.  Recommend using `fgets()` and lop off its potential trailing `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux yepp, you're right, of course, that was just lazy c&p. I didn't want to rewrite the whole thing. There's a good reason I put "// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!" in my example codes ;-) I also think that the inclusion of the whole `*scanf()` family into the standard was a bad idea to start with. In almost all cases a handwritten parser is simpler, lighter,  safer, more flexible, and less error-prone. Do we really need inverse functions for the `*printf()` group?

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: the function: `loadFromFile()` contains several problems 1) it does not tell the caller when the input file is completely read.  2) it returns the contents of a global variable, BUT the caller is not paying any attention to the returned value.  3) the input of 'employee->name' is not limited to any max length, so if the input file contains a name field that is 40 or more chars long, a buffer overflow will occur, resulting in undefined behavior.  4) Each call to `fscanf()` needs to check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: 1) the function: `saveToFile()`: My comments about the calls to `fscanf()` for employee->name also need to be applied to the inputting of the 'newfile' name.  2) the function: `saveToFile()` is never called by the rest of the posted code.

Comment: there is (in the posted code) only one file involved, so why is the variable: `employeeNumb` declared using the `static` modifier?

Comment: it is best to separate the description of a struct from the `typedef` that declares a type name for that struct